# XAMPP: pros and cons of VC6 vc VC9

Tags: php, xampp

Is there any advantage of using XAMPP compiled with VC9 as compared to one with VC6?

I noticed that XAMPP offers VC6 on their official download page, but if you go under previous versions, you can download the VC9 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC6 compiler is no longer maintained and VC9 will require the VC9 run-time DLL if I am not mistaken. VC6 is prior to .NET

Comment: Would that be the reason Microsoft is not offering VC6 version of their MS SQL for PHP? Starting version 3.0, only VC9 is available. If so, it sounds like it would be a good idea to switched to VC9-compiled PHP.. but I don't know how that would impact compatibility with older but useful tools.

Comment: You should only have to ensure that the Apache server and PHP are VC9 as I think they are not fully interchangeable but as far as I know you should be able to run most modules for PHP under either setup

Answer (score 0):

No. That only restricts which compiler/ABI must be used to build third-party modules (e.g. mod_wsgi).